# How to process submit data from complex Angular.js web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, form-submit

My web form (built with Bootstrap 3 and Angular.js 1.3) is lengthy and mildly dynamic. In other words, there are a few cases of tabular arranged input fields and other regular input fields with an associated "Add another" button, as well as some input fields that toggle (hide/show) based on the input or selection in preceding fields. In the controller JS, I set up an object in scope to hold all the form data as follows:

```
// Angular.js controller function
$scope.formData = {};
```

In the form's HTML, I backed all the fields with `ng-model` as follows:

```
<html data-ng-app="formApp">
  <body>
    <form class="form form-horizontal" data-ng-controller="formController">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" data-ng-model="formData.username" class="form-control" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-maxlength="8" required>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So by the time the form is filled, `$scope.formData` would have the following structure:

**`$scope.formData`** =>

```
  { "username": "jdoe",
    "roles": [
      "Employee", "Lead Engineer", "Coordinator"
    ],
    "location": "Palo Alo, CA",
    "and so": "on..."
  }
```

I want to use `$http` to asynchronously *post* the data to an ASP.NET generic HTTP handler, which will process the form submission and respond back in JSON format. What is the recommended approach to post the data? When I use `JSON.parse($scope.formData)`, the object is broken into individual request parameters and not submitted as a single object. And if I do get the object across as single object, how do I process the form submitted data? Ideally, I want to convert that entire `formData` object into a C# DTO object that I can work with on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can submit your $scope.formData as it is with $http() using the post method and then on the server side you can get your request data deserialized using Newtonsoft https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

maybe doing something like this

```
fromData =  JSON.stringify($scope.formData)

$http.post('/someUrl', {fromData:  fromData})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

server will be something like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string jsonstring)
{
     GenerForm frm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenerForm>(json);
     string username = frm.username;      
}
```

// you need to define class

```
class GenerForm {
    string username {get;set;};
    List<string> roles {get; set;};
    List<string> location {get; set;};
    // and so on
 }
```

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 2.0, so don't have access to Nuget. Is there a way to install JSON.net?

Comment: review this link and I think you need to add System.Web.Script.Serialization 
[linke](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-with-a-jQu)

Comment: Even in the provided link, I don't see how the submitted data is accessed, since the example involves posting an empty object as data. In the generic HTTP handler, I tried accessing the submitted data as a request parameter: `context.Request.Params["formData"]` but that returns an empty string. On the `$http`/Javascript side, I am using `$http.post('http://url', { formData: JSON.stringify($scope.formData) })` and I can see the request payload in Chrome developer tools sending the stringified version of the data. But I am unable to retrieve that on the server side.

Comment: for some reason, `context.Request.Params["formData"]` does not work, but a SO post led me to use `string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();` which works, but I am not very happy using since I would rather access the submitted request parameter value by its name.